# Accessing params hash from a partial in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a standard view in Rails, you can access the `params` hash as if you were in a controller, but I can't get this to work within a partial.

> undefined method `parameters' for nil:NilClass

I could pass the params to the partial using the `locals` option, but this partial is used a lot and I thought there must be a better way of doing it.

Anything that tries to access params will cause it to fail:

```
<% params %>
```

I've noticed that I only get the error when accessing from some views. On other view it works fine.

Comment: Can you add the line which gave this error?

Comment: `undefined method `parameters' for nil:NilClass` implies that the line you posted isn't the one erroring. Could you post the exact line that raises this error?

Comment: Does it need to be in a partial? do you just want to display the params on all views in development? Just curious, why are you doing this in multiple partials?

Comment: @fontno I'm using a partial in a json.erb template so that I can include the JSON for a user in multiple different views. I have a method on the User model called `avatar_url` that I call from within this partial. Sometimes I might want to use a size other than the default for the URL of the avatar, so I try to call `user.avatar_url(size: params[:avatar_size])`. This is where I (sometimes) encounter the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using locals you can do something like this:

```
<%= render :partial => "your_partial", :locals => { :parameters => params } %>
```

and this to inspect the variable:

```
<%= parameters.inspect %>
```

Comment: `params.inspect` gives me the same error. As I said above, this partial is used a lot so I was hoping I didn't have to go through and change the locals for each one. I wouldn't mind doing this all that much, but I was hoping there was a better way.